# Vue3 - vuetify - items/components in v-window and v-window-item are accessed/mounted many many times

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I noticed some strange behavior in a certain component that was placed inside a Vuetify3 v-window and v-window-item. The component was mounted twice while there was no trigger to be mounted more than once. After some digging I found that the placement within the v-window-item was the culprit. I can't really find a CodeSandbox with functional Vuetify3 but I do a simple code snippet:

```
 <template>
   <v-window
     v-model="window"
     show-arrows
   >
     <v-window-item
       v-for="n in length"
       :key="n"
     >

       <v-card height="200px" class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
         <v-btn
               variant="text"
               color="teal-accent-4">
               {{ getButtonName(n)}}
          </v-btn>
       </v-card>
     </v-window-item>
   </v-window>
 </template>

 <script>
 export default {
   data: () => ({
     length: 5,
     window: 0,
   }),
   methods: {
     getButtonName(n) {
       const ran = Math.random(1000);
       console.log('getting button name', n, ran);
       return `button${ran}`;
     },
   },
 };
 </script>
```

After opening the page, the first window item is rendered but the button is obtained 3 times, according to the console:

- getting button name 1 0.880447001734046
- getting button name 1 0.12339242677447548
- getting button name 1 0.5819716947412081

after clearing the console and clicking on the arrow to display the 2nd window-item:

- getting button name 1 0.7352073450391876
- getting button name 2 0.032674923815439794
- getting button name 1 0.9072690439233826
- getting button name 2 0.582529957055983
- getting button name 1 0.4787895716502588
- getting button name 2 0.23574469420588073
- getting button name 1 0.369508635398311
- getting button name 2 0.8050071805866972

and after clearing the console and getting the 3rd window item:

- getting button name 1 0.08513504512629355
- getting button name 2 0.4603523826341478
- getting button name 3 0.109863696712585
- getting button name 1 0.4509607677095986
- getting button name 2 0.5470585689729199
- getting button name 3 0.6822916650361945
- getting button name 1 0.01310028228219795
- getting button name 2 0.35570430336356607
- getting button name 3 0.9926557123169946
- getting button name 1 0.0467985490894256
- getting button name 2 0.683899325755521
- getting button name 3 0.05793793975985917

I want every component/item in a window-item to be rendered/accessed only once, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. The window-items are [lazy loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading).
Observe a window-item in the DOM before accessing it, you'll see nothing inside is rendered:

```html
<div class="v-window-item" style="display: none;">
  <!---->
</div>
```

Only after sliding the window into view does it become rendered:

```html
<div class="v-window-item v-window-item--active" style="">
  <div class="v-card v-theme--light ...">
    <button type="button">
      <span>button0.08513504512629355</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where it then remains a rendered (and re-rendered) part of the DOM for the life of the page.  Even though you're only viewing one window item at a time, the previous window items are still part of the DOM, just hidden now.  This is why the console.logs increase by one as more windows/buttons get rendered. The benefit of lazy-loading is that you don't start off having to render/re-render *all* these items after initial load.

Comment: Thanks, still wondering. I modified the aforementioned length variable such there is only 1 window-item. After loading the page, the button method is still invoked 3 times. Although there is only 1 window item. Can you explain this behavior? Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I think the console.logs happening in threes, regardless of number of windows, is related to some internal changes to the component causing rerenders on load and when transitioning.  Could be a Vuetify bug.  Sorry I can't help more. You can try [asking the Vuetify team](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify#%EF%B8%8F-questions)